# how do i get the selected node from jstree

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jstree

i have the following code to load a `jstree` control. data is loaded to the `jstree` as `json`.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;">
            <div id="Div_jstree"></div>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top;">
            <div id="Div_txta"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>
    <script> 

        //load the data from ajax and populate the child nodes
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/GetData',
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#Div_jstree').on('select_node.jstree', function (event, data) {

                       console.log( $("#Div_jstree").jstree("get_selected").text() );

                        var htmlta = '<br><div style="display:inline-block;" ' + 'id=div-' + data.studentid + '>' +
                            '<textarea style=width:100px;height:100px;visibility:visible;' + 'id=' + data.studentid + '>' + 'name here' 
                             + ':</textarea>' +
                            '<input type="button" class="del" value="Del"' + 'id=' + data.id + ' /></div>';
                        $('#Div_txta').append(htmlta);

                        $(document).on('click', '.del', function () {
                            $(this).closest('div').remove();
                        });
                    })
                    .jstree({
                        "core": {
                            "data": data,
                            "themes": {
                                "url": true,
                                "icons": true,
                                "dots": true
                            },
                            'check_callback': true
                        },
                        "plugins": ["dnd"]
                    });
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
    });
}
```

here is teh action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
{
    var tvdata = new List<TVCVM>();
    tvdata.Add(new TVCVM { id = "n1", parent = "#", text = "Cardiology", value = "10", @class= "parentNode"});
    tvdata.Add(new TVCVM { id = "n2", parent = "#", text = "Physio", value = "11", @class = "parentNode" });
    tvdata.Add(new TVCVM { id = "n3", parent = "n2", text = "Bopara", value = "100", @class = "childNode" });
    tvdata.Add(new TVCVM { id = "n4", parent = "n2", text = "Wickram", value = "101", @class = "childNode" });

    return Json(tvdata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

here is the VM

```
 public class TVCVM
    {
        public String id { get; set; }
        public string @class { get; set; }
        public string parent { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

ajax receives data because it shows the tree nodes with their text but it shows the following errors:

1. `$("#Div_jstree").jstree("get_selected").text();` throws the error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).jstree(...).text is not a function

2. when i tried to access the json data in htmlta eg: `data.id` gives

> undefined error and for data[0]`.id`, id is not defined error.

How do i fix theses issues?
the in the click event when i tried to access

Answer (score -1):

For 1 - use `data.node.text` to get node text, so replace `$("#Div_jstree").jstree("get_selected").text();` with `console.log( data.node.text );`

For 2 - use `data.node.id` to get node id, so replace `'<input type="button" class="del" value="Del"' + 'id=' + data.id + ' /></div>'` with `'<input type="button" class="del" value="Del"' + 'id=' + data.node.id` + ' />'`

Comment: i would like to extend this question, how would i store the mutiple values in a node such as GteData() return a collection of a class i need to store those property value in nodes

Comment: You can store any values in attributes of `li` elements that jsTree will build. To do that, pass that info in `li_attr` key of your json like this: `{ "id" : "...", "parent" : "...", "text" : "...", "li_attr": { "data-key1": "value1", "data-key2": "value2" } }`

Comment: data binding happens through ajax so i need to add attribute `li_attr` to TVCVM class so that would internally create that attribute as a json key, this something i havent tried before

Comment: Yes, you have to add it to json sent through ajax

Comment: there is a problem with creating dat-key attribute 'cus C# will not let me create a property with the dash

Comment: I would suggest you to discuss this in a new question.